# how to set upload_tmp_dir value on IIS 7.5 server for drupal 6??

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, drupal

In our .htaccess put: php_value upload_tmp_dir /path/to/dir

However, I've never got this to work.

coding: The alternative is: ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/path/to/dir');

But again, I've never got this to work

If we are on shared hosting, then yes, it's most likely your host's fault. We are also correct in that this directive can only be modified in the .ini/.conf files.

ini_set() will never work because it's too late in the process for that to have any effect; the server will already have tried (and failed) to write to the upload directory by the time your PHP script is executed.

can any one have better solution on this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `phpinfo()`, it will tell you which php.ini file it uses in row 'Loaded Configuration File'.

Find `upload_tmp_dir` there and edit it to your setup. Restart IIS.

Comment: yes by this we can get upload_tmp_dir path

eg: upload_tmp_dir C:\Windows\Temp

and we requires this path should be as same as open_basedir for file upload process in drupal 6.

otherwise it will raises the open_basedir restriction and uplaoded tmp  file is not within allowed path.

will there be any option to make both same via htaccess since site is on shared hosting environment?

still it be the only way to manage php.ini configuration values???

Comment: htaccess is for apache, IIS won't read it IMO. It should be possible to set upload_tmp_dir per virtualhost (or whatever is't called in IIS).